# Why is the message not sending on the set-mod-log channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm not quite sure why this part is not functioning when the command is executed. The message is not being sent in the set mod-log channel of the guild. However, the code below is the exact same code that my kick commands have; and it's functioning perfectly well.

```
let channel = db.fetch(`modlog_${message.guild.id}`)
if (channel == null) return;

if (!channel) return;

const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor(`${message.guild.name} Modlogs`, message.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }))
    .setColor(colored[~~(Math.random() * colored.length)])
    .setThumbnail(banMember.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
    .setFooter(message.guild.name, message.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true, format: 'png' }))
    .addField("**Moderation**", "Addrole")
    .addField("**Added Role to**", rMember.user.username)
    .addField("**Role Added**", role.name)
    .addField("**Responsible Mod**", message.author.username)
    .addField("**Date**", message.createdAt.toLocaleString())
    .setTimestamp();

var sChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(channel)
if (!sChannel) return;
sChannel.send(embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing how you handled your command, the channel most likely wasn't found at some point.

You should try to debug each state the channel and sChannel goes through by logging it after each declaration or changes to make sure everything exists as intended

Comment: @Meko which means that `channel` is either null or undefined. You should recheck your `db.fetch` part

Comment: But like I said above, the code is the exact same code that is in my kick and ban command; and it's working perfectly fine.

Comment: @Meko I mean, there isn't that much lines in your code, and the way you handle it suggests that the problem is coming from your channel declaration. What would it cost you to double check, even if it used to work ?

Comment: @Meko what does the output of a `console.log(channel)` looks like ?

Comment: Nothing appears on my terminal. `console.log(sChannel)` and `console.log(channel)` doesn't log anything in my terminal.

Comment: @Meko what if you place the `console.log(channel)` between the channel declaration and the first `if` ?

Comment: That's what I did but still nothing happened.

Comment: @Meko then the problem is either coming from somewhere higher in your code, or from your `db.fetch` function, but since we do not know anything about any of these two, it will be hard for us to provide a precise answer

Comment: @Meko the first thing I would try would be to `await` the `db.fetch` function. Then you should try logging every single step to see which one is blocking everything. For example, using a `console.log('1')` for the very first check, then `...log('2')` after the next one, etc...

Comment: I did what you told me `await` and `log` but the last part didn't log.

Comment: @Meko where exactly did it stop ?

Comment: In the last 2 parts of the code. ```let channel = db.fetch(`modlog_${message.guild.id}`)``` and the ```let sChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(channel)```. Both of them didn't log.

Comment: @Meko I do not really know how your database works, but do you think there could be another way for you to find that channel ?